# Local File IO in Chrome extension

Tags: file-io, google-chrome-extension

I use NPAPI in chrome extension for File IO before, but recently this is blocked by Google Chrome 32.

I tried NaCl and Native Messaging API, but these seems to run in a sandbox and local File IO is forbidden.

How can I do this now?

Comment: Native Messaging lets you run a binary file of your choosing (given that its already installed on the desktop). It can be anything: even external UI for file handling. In that sense it does not run in a sandbox, as suggested by the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be able to get a reference to a non-sandboxed FileSystem by calling chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry from javascript and then passing this reference into PPAPI.

If this doesn't work, we should create a bug on crbug and it should be made to work!

Comment: I see chrome.fileSystem API exists in Chrome apps API, but I am developing a Chrome extension.

Comment: Ah, of course. Well, you can install both an extension and an app, and have them communicate with each other using message passing.

Comment: Thx, I find that Chrome FileSystem API does not operate on the real file system, it is on a sandbox one. But what I want is operation on the real file.

Comment: Yes, you can get a real filesystem directory by calling chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry with the directory option.

Comment: I input "chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry({type: "openDirectory"}, function(entry){console.log(entry)});" in background console, but it only says undefined. What's wrong?

Comment: Did it even pop up a dialog to have you select a directory? Make sure you added {"fileSystem": ["directory", ...]} to the manifest. You'll probably also want "retainEntries" so that when you restart the app you can keep the fileSystem reference working.

Comment: No, I cannot see any dialog. I added {"fileSystem": ["write", "directory"]}. Is there any other setting for this? By the way, I don't want to fire a dialog, I need everything work in background without manual effort.

Comment: It can't be done without manual effort. It is a security feature of chrome apps, that they don't have access to your filesystem without a user authorizing it.